# Bootstrap Navtabs as Buttons

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to js/bootstrap and am reading about it from the official website.
I'm having problem with the nav-tabs. In the official example, they are taking the user to some other url, like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Click</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Play</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Hours Viewed</a></li>
</ul>
```

But my requirement is to call some js method on click on these tabs. 
Is it possible using nav-tabs ? or do I have to use buttons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the native comportement of the `<a>` with JS. For example, if you set something like this, the link will execute your `doSomething` function but not link you to another page :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="doSomething()">click me</a>
```

To go further, if you want to better separate the JS and the HTML (good practice), avoid the inline-javascript and prefer the use of listener : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is to add an `onclick` attribute for each `<a>` tag...

Maybe something like this...

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li><a onclick="clickFirst();" href="#">Click</a></li>
       <li><a onclick="clickSecond();" href="#">Play</a></li>
       <li><a onclick="clickThird();" href="#">Hours Viewed</a></li>
</ul>
```

and add this in your script tag...

```
function clickFirst() {
    alert('First anchor clicked...');
}

function clickSecond() {
    alert('Second anchor clicked...');
}

function clickThird() {
    alert('Third anchor clicked...');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bootstrap javascript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/). And this one is about [tab](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).

Here is a sample code:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```